# Having separate PHP functions for individual option values html

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, html-table

Is it possible to call a function when a different option value is select from a select box? the select box consists of 'approved' 'pending' and 'dissapproved'. I have a form which will automatically flag the submission as 'pending' when entered in the database.

When changed by an admin from 'pending' to 'approved' or 'disapproved' this will run a SQL query to update the information in the table. What table structure would be best suited to this? and how can I ensure that when the option value is changed a CSS class is applied to the affected row of table cells. Which will remain the same unless changed. I have tried with jQuery however I do not feel it meets my requirements

Code:

```
 <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Orders")
    or die (mysql_error());
    ?>
    <form method ="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <table style ="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Ordered By</th>
    <th>Supplier</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
    <th>Requested By</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))



{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_n`enter code here`o[]" value="' . $row['Orderno'] . '"/>    </td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_date[]" value="' . $row['Orderdate'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_ordered_by[]" value="' . $row['Orderedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_supplier[]" value="' . $row['Supplier'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_total_price[]" value="' . $row['totalprice'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_requested_by[]" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select name="order_status[]">';
    echo '<option></option>';
    echo '<option>Approved</option>';
    echo '<option>Pending</option>';
    echo '<option>Dissaproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
?>
```

Current jQuery to change table row colour, however I would like to add a CSS class to each option value and when the status is changed, this is reflected in the database, applying the correct class.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var color = ['none', '#DEF3CA', '#EECFA1', '#FFCCCC'];

    $('table').on('change','select', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').css('background', color[$(':selected', this).index()]); 
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Table CSS:

```
 <style type = "text/css">
    table,td {
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width:auto;
    font-weight: none;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-style: normal;
    border-collapse:separate;


    }

    td {
    width:250px;
    padding:15px;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid; 
    }
    </style>
```

SendEmail script to email each person based on 'Requestedby'

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['order_requested_by']))
    {
    $row_count = count($_POST['order_requested_by']);

    for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++)
    {

    $to = $_POST['order_requested_by'][$i];
    $subject = "Order Status";
    $message = "Your order number: " . $_POST['order_no'][$i] ." ". "is" ." ".            $_POST['order_status'][$i];
        $orderdate = "Order date: " . $_POST['order_date'][$i];
        $from = "no-reply@.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$orderdate,$headers);
        echo "Mail Sent.";

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the selection value to another page via a variable and then

```
$selection = $_POST['variable']
if ($selection == "1") {
    ....
    }
elseif ($selection == "2") {
    ....
    }
```