# Correct method to store option values in a select box

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, html-table

Sorry to post a question which has already been posted, however I am really struggling to get this functionality to work. When I change a select box option value I want it to remain the same on page refresh or logout. Must I use AJAX/PHP to get this to work? I have tried to do this to no avail. [Possible to run DB update function when dropdown is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300358/possible-to-run-db-update-function-when-dropdown-is-selected).

My code looks like:

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_no[]" value="' . $row['Orderno'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_date[]" value="' . $row['Orderdate'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_ordered_by[]" value="' . $row['Orderedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_supplier[]" value="' . $row['Supplier'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_total_price[]" value="' . $row['totalprice'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_requested_by[]" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select id ="id" name="id">';
    echo '<option value = "1" class = "pending">Pending</option>';
    echo '<option value = "2" class = "approved">Approved</option>';
    echo '<option value = "3" class ="disapproved">Disapproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Like said in the answer below, jQuery is your friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the selected status should be an attribute of the order.  So you should make an ajax call to PHP (or whatever your server-side language is) to update the status when the selectbox changes.  And the selectbox itself should look something like:

```
echo '<select id ="id" name="id">';
echo '<option value = "1" class = "pending"' . ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
echo '<option value = "2" class = "approved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
echo '<option value = "3" class ="disapproved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

I don't think cookies should be necessary

Comment: I received an unexpected ';' on implementation when I ran the above code

Comment: would this be the correct way to include the AJAX request on my page.<script type="text/javascript">
$('#id').change(function(){
   var val = $('#id').val();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/test/myfile.php',//url of the file
        data: val,
        success: function(msg){
      }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: @m1243 That's not the only way to do it, but you certainly can do it that way (see also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  The data param needs to be passed as a key/value pair though, not just as a value.  So something like `data: {status: val}` _should_ work (or at least be close enough to get you on the right track)

Answer (score 1):

You can store selected value in cookie, have a look at [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

Or if you are able to identify the user somehow, you can store the value on the server and render it right away. But when you state, that selected value should be persisted even after logout, you will need cookie anyway to store some identification token.

Comment: Thank you, when using jQuery will this work on multiple computers viewing the table? I couldn't get the cookie functionality to work when selecting an option value

Comment: Just to make sure.. Saying 'multiple computers' - you mean, once one user selects a value, you want all others to see that selection?

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct the changes would need to be reflected across different PC's

Comment: Ok, then forget about cookie, all you need is updating the DB according to answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12300358/944681). Btw. quite unusual requirement..

Comment: Ok thanks, it's so an admin can see orders which are approved,pending or disapproved. I couldn't think of a better way to tackle this. Thank you

Comment: Oh dear ;) What you really need is to update your order status in database. Asking about persisting state of html select is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thankyou :s one last thing is when a user fills out the form the details are added to the Database, under an orders table. I have managed to set a flag of 0 for all orders, shall I add an extra column or a new table for approved orders?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the the following jquery and ajax code to do this

```
$('#id').change(function(){
   var val = $('#id').val();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',//url of the file
        data: val,
        success: function(msg){
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example on [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) that uses a autocomplete box. IMHO much nicer than the select dropdown.
It has all the AJAX functionality that with few lines of you get a working example:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```